# What is the difference between écouteur and écouteuse?

Tags: genre

It's understandable that a person or an adjective can have masculine or feminine forms.

But how can we determine the gender of an earphone? Is it based on its shape or the gender of its owner?"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  An object, whether an earphone or a car or a house or a book... doesn't change gender according to its owner. I wonder if you aren't confusing two different meanings of *écouteur*. See [here](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9couteur). Meaning 1 is someone who listens, it has a masculine and a feminine form according to the person being described.  Meaning 2. is an object ("earphone") and it is masculine, whoever its owner, it doesn't have a feminine form.

Comment: @None Thanks for the reply. The meaning 1 is where I'm lost. It totally make sense to use masculine and feminine to describe a person, instead of an equipment.

Comment: @sleepy: the piece of equipment is *always* called *un écouteur*. French only has masculine and feminine genders, so the piece of equipment has to be one or the other, and the default gender is usually the masculine.

Comment: *J'ai branché mes écouteurs sur ma liseuse.*

Comment: Any bilingual dictionary will tell you that in French the device for listening is *écouteur* and it is masculine.  [écouteurs (masculine, plural)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/earphones) ; [écouteur masculine noun earpiece (of phone)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/%C3%A9couteur)

Comment: @PeterShor On a tendance à utiliser _écouteurs_ au pluriel. Sans doute parce que nous avons deux oreilles.

Comment: @Frank S'il n'y a qu'un *écouteur*, on a tendance à l'appeler ***une oreillette***.